# Is there any limitation to use ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am developing a product. There, i am separating a page with so many templates, use atleast 5-8 ng-include per page. is there any problem to use so many ng-include in a page?

Comment: why you have that many ng-include on page? any reason please?

Comment: splitting a big html page into small

Comment: no problem.. you can even have 100s of them, even though that would be a bad design

Comment: That will make 6-9 HTTP queries to display the page instead of 1 (not counting those for the images, etc., of course). It can, or can not be a problem depending on your target. On slow, high latency mobile networks, it might make a significant difference.

Comment: If the `ng-include`s are not conditional or dynamic you might consider compiling the larger template using a build tool like Gulp.

Comment: @sdgluck pls give some usefull links for gulp (with examples to compiling templates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major problem is that each ng-include generates a http request, which will impact the page load times.

If all your doing is splitting up a page, you have a couple of options:

1. Create directives, if your HTML can be used in others areas of your app.
2. Use a templating engine like handlebars and a preprocessor to combine all the partials, in to a single page, like GulpJS or Grunt (i prefer Gulp).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the reason behind so many partials your use of it may be justified. Generally when you have a lot of partials, it would be better for performance reason to use the $cacheFactory.Cache to store and retrieve the data in the clients browser.